# Fade out entire page except some elements in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following HTML I have a two div panels. One is on the side with draggable elements and second is main-area where draggable div should be dropped. When drag starts I want the main-area to fade out except few divs which are calculated dynamically with each drag event. I'm using the .fade-out class but it doesn't really work, because an actual application has too many divs as children of main-area, so going through an HTML collection of required divs would not work. So what would be the best way to do this preferably using JavaScript only?

```
<div class="side-panel">
    <div draggable="true" ondrag="drag(event)"></div>
    <div draggable="true" ondrag="drag(event)"></div>
    <div draggable="true" ondrag="drag(event)"></div>
    <div draggable="true" ondrag="drag(event)"></div>
</div>
<div class="main-area">
    <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>


.fade-out {
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Comment: Can do this using css `visibility` but to do opacity would need to move those elements out of main and use positioning for them. Otherwise they inherit the parent opactiy

Comment: _"using the .fade-out class but it doesn't really work, because an actual application has too many divs as children of main-area, so going through an HTML collection of required divs would not work"_ What do you mean by "would not work"? Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to go about it, is to give alpha values to colors and background-colors instead of changing the opacity. So, it depends on what you have inside each div inside the main-area div.

An example would be,
Considering you have background color and/or some text, in each of those divs, you can give a class with properties

```
.fade-out {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

Then, for each div whose opacity doesn't change, you can give

```
.normal-opacity {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* 
 For demo
*/
.main-area > * {
  width  : 35px;
  height : 35px;
  display    : inline-block;
  background : purple;
}


.main-area.fade-out-unnecessary-children > :not(.wont-fade-out){
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-panel">
    <div draggable="true" ondrag="drag(event)"></div>
    <div draggable="true" ondrag="drag(event)"></div>
    <div draggable="true" ondrag="drag(event)"></div>
    <div draggable="true" ondrag="drag(event)"></div>
</div>
<div class="main-area fade-out-unnecessary-children">
    <div class="wont-fade-out" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="wont-fade-out" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
```

"When drag starts I want the main-area to fade out except few divs which are calculated dynamically with each drag event."
"...an actual application has too many divs as children of main-area, so going through an HTML collection of required divs would not work. "

1) If you can detect the "**few divs**" which should not *fade-out*, **add a class(.wont-fade-out) on each of these**.

```
<!-- Child element -->
<div class="wont-fade-out" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

2) On the `.main-area` **add a class as well(.fade-out-unnecessary-children)**.

```
<div class="main-area fade-out-unnecessary-children">
  <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="wont-fade-out" ></div>
  <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
```

3) After, you can do everything with CSS

```
.main-area.fade-out-unnecessary-children > :not(.wont-fade-out){
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```